# How to rename Bluetooth device in Windows 11 Pro 22H2?

Tags: windows-11, bluetooth, rename, windows-11-v22h2

All the guides that I managed to find (namely [this one](https://www.makeuseof.com/windows-11-rename-bluetooth-devices/), [this](https://windowsreport.com/windows-11-change-bluetooth-name/) and [this](https://www.laptopmag.com/how-to/rename-a-bluetooth-device-on-windows-11)) seems to be *pre 22H2*. The Control Panel section named *Hardware and Sound* → *Devices and Printers* seems to be no longer exiting in *22H2*.

Anyway, when I am clicking *Devices and Printers* (as instructed) instead of getting to good-old Control Panel view, I am redirected to *Settings* application to *Bluetooth & devices* section. And there is no even a trace of *Rename* functionality:

[image]

So... How to rename Bluetooth device in Windows 11 22H2? Or how to access Bluetooth's properties in this edition of Windows (where I should be able to rename a device).

Comment: Microsoft names them so as not to conflict. You probably need a registry hack to do what you want and then the hack will disappear with 23H2. I do not bother any more.

Comment: (1) When in *Settings > Devices > Bluetooth & other devices.*, if you click the device, do you have a pencil icon next to the name and can you click it to rename? (2) Run Device Manager, expand Bluetooth, click your device, click menu *Action > Devices and Printers*, double-click the device and go to the Bluetooth tab and change the name. Even if it works it might take a while to see.

Comment: @John As you can see in the depicted example, Microsoft does this very wrong and in fact do the conflict. I have two Edifier headphones, one at home and one at the office. Non of them is able to auto-connect after powering up. So each must be connected manually from my Windows. 95% of tries (as according to Murphy Laws) I am connecting the _wrong_ one. Veeeery frustrating.

Comment: I cannot see any settings to change the name. Very newest  Windows 11. Microsoft naming should accommodate similar devices.

Comment: https://github.com/btframework/BtDeviceRenamer

Comment: @harrymc (1) Items in this section (devices) are not clickable at all. No pencil on either clock or hover, sorry. All you have is the _Connect_ button and the three dot menu with _Connect_ and _Remove devices_ items (as in my screencast). (2) You have solved the mystery of getting to the old-good Control Panel device list, but it no longer works in terms of renaming device. Going as you advises (I know this path) and trying to rename a devices fails with any attempt being ignored. Device is not renamed after: 1, 3, 5 or 10 minutes and has the "old" name upon reopening device properties.

Comment: @MikePetrichenko A very cool piece of software, but I am hitting the wall with the "Run the app" part. As I don't have any C++ compiler and there are no releases or otherwise precompiled Windows 11 binaries (or I am blind).

Comment: Try to rename this device on another computer/device/phone, the name might stick if it's supported.

Comment: @trejder  https://github.com/btframework/BtDeviceRenamer/tree/main/C%2B%2B/build

Comment: @trejder https://github.com/btframework/BtDeviceRenamer/tree/main/VCL/build

Comment: @MikePetrichenko I had to delete my latest comment and revert your claim. No, unfortunately changes introduced in Windows 11 Pro 22H2 breaks even solution suggested by you. Running compiled version of this program does changes Bluetooth device's name. But the change is non-permanent. It is reverted back to the original one either on next Windows run or within a couple of minutes.

Comment: @trejde Sorry for delay with the answer. Was busy installing Win 11 on clean PC. Will check and try to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

It was a bit hidden, I have Windows in Polish, so I'm adding a step-by-step screenshoot.

`Bluetooth settings` -> `More devices settings and printers` -> <kbd>Right click</kbd> on device and `Properties` -> `Bluetooth` and you can now set new name. When you reconnect devices, the names will update.

[image: Step 1]

[image: Step 2]

[image: Step 3]

[image: Step 4]

[image: Step 5]

Comment: This is the exact way that is discussed in comments under question. For some reason, under my Windows 11 Pro this doesn't work at all. Changed name is accepted (no error after renaming the way you has shown and clicking _OK_), but never actually reflected (device name is **not** changed). I don't know why. Do you have Windows 11 Pro 22H2? Cause I suspect that 22H2 edition introduced the idea of no user rename for Bluetooth devices.

Comment: Yes, this is the latest stable bulid 10.0.22621.1848. Unfortunately, default name returns after restarting. It's very strange that Windows can't save these changes.

Comment: Łukasz, no, it is absolutely not very strange that Windows doesn't allow you to do something that you think is obvious! :) This is "The Microsoft way", a policy that Microsoft has for 40-50 years so far. Many, many years ago they'd a marketing slogan "Where do you want to go today?". During these times we were joking that no matter what you answer to that question, they will always take you there, where they want! :)

Comment: This solution also doesn't work for me (I have the most recent version of Win 11 with all updates).