# How to rename a sound bluetooth device and show it in the taskbar tray in Windows 11 23H2?

Tags: windows-11, bluetooth, windows-11-v23h2

I've read [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1790842/how-to-rename-bluetooth-device-in-windows-11-pro-22h2) and nothing there applies or works for me. I have my own screenshots plus my Windows version is 23H2.
I renamed one of my bluetooth devices. I rebooted after the rename. It's showing the new name under Settings -> System -> Sound but not in the system tray where I connect the device.

The first screenshot shows where I renamed it.
The second screenshot shows the new name. Same section where I renamed it.
However, in the 3rd screenshot in the taskbar tray, it's showing the original name.

How do I rename it for the taskbar tray?

[image]

[image]

[image]